# Can't set up SMTP server

Tags: email, postfix, mail-server

I am currently trying to set up an SMTP server on Ubuntu22.04, using the instructions from this tutorial: https://operavps.com/docs/install-smtp-server-on-ubuntu/  It says to use telnet to get the confirmation that it works, but the server isn't connecting.  Also, in the instructions, it says to create a ufw rule to allow ''Postfix SMTPS''  When I write out the rule this way, it says that it needs a to and from clause.  I'm trying to establish this Smtp server so I may receive updates for when there are problems with packages installing, as well as notices relating to things such as fail2ban and Osaac.  Please help me.

Comment: That tutorial appears to be full of typos - missing whitespace between commands and arguments, ‘’smart’’ quotes, etc.

Comment: Do not use any tutorials from random websites. Read the original documentation from Postfix website: http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html and comments in the sample configuration files provided with the distribution. Make some effort to understand how it works and what the configuration parameters actually mean.

Comment: Note a lot of VPSes block outgoing SMTP for abuse by other mail providers; if you're trying to set up Postfix and such, you need to be very careful understanding what can happen here if you set up an MSTP server.